# How to get single byte out of BitArray (without byte[])?

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering, is there a way to convert a BitArray into a byte (opposed to a byte array)? I'll have 8 bits in the BitArray..

```
 BitArray b = new BitArray(8);


//in this section of my code i manipulate some of the bits in the byte which my method was given. 

 byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
 b.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
```

This is what i have so far.... it doesn't matter if i have to change the byte array into a byte or if i can change the BitArray directly into a byte. I would prefer being able to change the BitArray directly into a byte... any ideas?

Comment: There's no point in using BitArray for a byte.  Just use the | and & operators on a byte.

Comment: `byte firstByte = bytes[0];`? (The last paragraph seems confusing.)

Comment: I can't seem to wrap my head around entirely using &. I'm use bit shift to access a bit and set it as i want. After i set it, i place it into a BitArray. Seemed the easiest way for me to understand.. If you can explain it to be in a concise way, i'll most definitely switch the way i'm handling it... PS. thanks for the comments/help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an extension method

```
    static Byte GetByte(this BitArray array)
    {
        Byte byt = 0;
        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
            byt = (byte)((byt << 1) | (array[i] ? 1 : 0));
        return byt;
    }
```

You can use it like so

```
        var array = new BitArray(8);
        array[0] = true;
        array[1] = false;
        array[2] = false;
        array[3] = true;

        Console.WriteLine(array.GetByte()); <---- prints 9
```

9 decimal = 1001 in binary